# Images save to saved pics and retrieving back and displaying in my app in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello Friends I am New to WP7

i am working on small app now..
In that App i take one Pic from my camera and trying to save that in saved pictures with some name and i like to retrieve that Images and display again in my App Gallery screen

I am Using Pivot control for this app 
in my first PivotItem Name is Gallery and second PivotItem name is Camera

Now i am working with camera fine
After taking my picture from camera i like to add some Note for that and save to my saved images and retrieving same image back and display in Gallery with Note wt i save

can any one say 
how can i complete this App in good way

Code for save Images im using 
mainpage.xaml.cs

```
    private void saveimg_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
       {
        string fileName = myValue.ToShortDateString() + ".jpg";
        var library = new MediaLibrary();
        //library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ChosenPhoto);
        library.SavePicture(fileName, imageBits);
        MessageBox.Show("Photo Saved to Picture Hub");

        }
```

I need to Retrieve that that saved Image and display in my App when it loaded

Comment: Can I use a SQLite for store the images because i have note (or) comment for every image what i take

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access your image once it has been saved in the Media Library, you should also save it to the Isolated Storage.

Here is a tutorial that shows how to do that:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

Comment: hay Olivier Thanks for Your Replay .I like to create one Folder with my App name in My Gallery for Example you can download this App and see http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/super-camera/f5a24e8b-5add-4487-80b2-3b92abf6a83e  like this app i am also trying to create one Folder can you Help me for that .....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save the image to Isolated Storage and Pictures Gallery. When wanting to see the image through the app, use image from Isolated Storage.

No need to use SQLite, use index numbers to save your image in Isolated storage, and also store comments with index numbers, that might ease you.